# Fastest way to send large blobs of data from one program to another in Windows?

Tags: windows, ipc, pipe, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

I need to send large blobs of data (~10MB) from one program to another in Windows 7.  I would like a method that allows for at least a gigabyte per second total throughput with very low system load.  To simplify this, all blobs may be the same size, and one program may be a child process of the other.

Method 1: [Memory map the same file in both programs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551%28VS.85%29.aspx): CreateFileMapping() / MapViewOfFile()

In this case, the memory mapped file(s) presumably contains room for several blobs in a ring buffer.  There would need to be some external mechanism to synchronize access to the ring buffer.

Method 2: [Create named data sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h90dkhs0%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Method 3: [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (suggested by Hristo Iliev below, thanks!)

Method 4: Read/write files on a RAM disk.

Method 5: Read/write to an anonymous pipe.

Method ?: Anything else? Perhaps write over TCP, use MPI, ...

I know that memory-mapped files (method 1) are considered the standard solution to this problem :)

- How fast are memory-mapped files?  (rough order of magnitude)
- Is there an even faster method?
- How much worse is the performance of the other methods?  Which ones of them can hit GB/sec throughput?
- If using memory mapped files, what is the best way for the programs to synchronize access to the data being passed? (ie: how would the producer indicate to the consumer that a new blob is available, and how would the consumer indicate it is done with a particular blob?)
- If using memory mapped files, is it better to have one file for all blobs together (ring buffer in a file), or one file for each blob (ring buffer of files)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and have the first process to directly post the data into the address space of the second process. You'd need to develop a protocol of some kind. For example, the second process could send the virtual address of its receive buffer to the first process via a named pipe or a shared memory block, then the first process copies the data using `WriteProcessMemory` and when it is finished, signals the second one via a semaphore or something. This ought to be the fastest way to send data between two processes as it involves a single copy operation. The first process would need to obtain the proper rights on the second one and that should not be a problem as long as both processes belong to the same user.

Comment: Interesting method, I knew there were options I wasn't thinking of.  Is `WriteProcessMemory` likely to be faster than `MapViewOfFile`?  The existance of another protocol to synchronize passing the data is assumed in either case :)

Comment: @AlexI, there is not much documentation on the inner working of `WriteProcessMemory`, but I would assume that is does direct data copy in kernel mode. With a shared file view, one has to first copy data from the first process into the shared arena and then to copy it from the arena and into the memory of the second process. Unless data can be manipulated directly while being inside the shared segment, this double copy process is likely to be slower than the WPM method.

Comment: By the way, the MPI standard provides similar functionality using one-sided operations, but the implementation is quite awkward (as it has to be very portable).